# canvas.setWidth(NUMBER) distorts the objects

Tags: fabricjs

After changing the canvas width 
canvas.setWidth(NUMBER)
the objects get distorted. I created a demo 
https://codesandbox.io/s/0py34838jp
change the input field to change the canvas size.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was subtle and deserves to be explained for future references.

FabricJs supports retina scaling and on interactive canvas you have both a lowerCanvas and an upperCanvas.

On the other hand in all the react apps that initialize fabricJS on a componentDidMount that has a canvas node in the render function, React does not know about the canvas container div, or the upperCanvas at all, nor does it know about the retina scaling.

So what was happening was that on your onChange event you were modifying the canvas size with setDimensions.

setDimensions was changing the canvas width to X * pixelScaling (device dependant ), while the height was still at original height * pixelScaling.

a div container with a css rule was still showing everything at the correct dimension

On react re renderind after setState, the property on the canvas was set back to X and probably react-dom was then changing some width of some canvas to X ( i have no idea which was targeting since the dom nodes were outside its control, but we should verify ).

a setDimension trigger a rerender of the canvas at the next animation frame.

Before the animation frame started, react completed its dom changes and so the rect was redrawn on a canvas element that is wide X, but styled thinking that is X * pixelRatio, and that is why it appeared stretched.

FabricJs canvas should be mounted and let it go probably, not influenced with react dom changes, because the 2 library are not cooperating on this.

What could be added is a method to instantiate a canvas from a react jsx without fabricJS messing up with the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @asturur for the help.
I needed to listen for the componentDidUpdate then set the width/height
Here is the a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/0py34838jp

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.canvasFabric.setWidth(this.state.width);
}
```